# Overheating problem Ubuntu 20.04, false signal?

Tags: command-line, lenovo, fan, overheating, temperature

I'm on Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 with a LENOVO ThinkPad L13 Yoga.

For a few days, Ubuntu has been crashing and turning off suddenly.

Looking at logs with `journalctl` shows that the problem is overheating,

```
Jun 30 13:13:18 siavash-fra thermald[1184]: critical temp reached
Jun 30 13:13:19 siavash-fra thermald[1184]: critical temp reached
-- Reboot --
```

although there's no sign of overheating. So I monitored the temperature with `sensors`. Here are the values after boot with no task running:

```
ucsi_source_psy_USBC000:001-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:           0.00 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)
curr1:         0.00 A  (max =  +0.00 A)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +42.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +39.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +42.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +38.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +41.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

BAT0-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:          16.93 V  

ucsi_source_psy_USBC000:002-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:           5.00 V  (min =  +5.00 V, max = +15.00 V)
curr1:         3.00 A  (max =  +3.00 A)

iwlwifi_1-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +49.0°C  

thinkpad-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
fan1:           0 RPM
temp1:         +1.0°C  
temp2:         +1.0°C  
temp3:         +4.0°C  
temp4:        +60.0°C  
temp5:        +63.0°C  
temp6:        +63.0°C  
temp7:        +16.0°C  
temp8:        +66.0°C  
temp9:        +64.0°C  
temp10:        +3.0°C  
temp11:       -80.0°C  
temp12:        +0.0°C  
temp13:        +0.0°C  
temp14:        +0.0°C  
temp15:       +66.0°C  
temp16:        +0.0°C  

nvme-pci-0300
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +37.9°C  (low  = -20.1°C, high = +77.8°C)
                       (crit = +81.8°C)
Sensor 1:     +37.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +40.0°C  (crit = +95.0°C)
```

But when I run a python script for example, in less than two seconds the temp reaches critical and it crashes:

```
iwlwifi_1-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +50.0°C  

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +96.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +73.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +73.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +71.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +96.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

BAT0-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:          16.93 V  

ucsi_source_psy_USBC000:002-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:           5.00 V  (min =  +5.00 V, max = +15.00 V)
curr1:         3.00 A  (max =  +3.00 A)

ucsi_source_psy_USBC000:001-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:           0.00 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)
curr1:         0.00 A  (max =  +0.00 A)

thinkpad-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
fan1:           0 RPM
temp1:         +1.0°C  
temp2:         +1.0°C  
temp3:         +4.0°C  
temp4:        +60.0°C  
temp5:        +63.0°C  
temp6:        +63.0°C  
temp7:        +16.0°C  
temp8:        +66.0°C  
temp9:        +64.0°C  
temp10:        +3.0°C  
temp11:       -80.0°C  
temp12:        +0.0°C  
temp13:        +0.0°C  
temp14:        +0.0°C  
temp15:       +66.0°C  
temp16:        +0.0°C  

nvme-pci-0300
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +39.9°C  (low  = -20.1°C, high = +77.8°C)
                       (crit = +81.8°C)
Sensor 1:     +39.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +96.0°C  (crit = +95.0°C)
```

It actually doesn't feel even warm. Can this be a false signal? Can the temp reach so high in less than 2 seconds?

I use windows alongside and I don't have overheating or crashes in there. Btw, it shows `fan1: 0 RPM` but I can hear and feel the fan is working.

Comment: Thermal shutdown is done by the BIOS (motherboard), not by Ubuntu.

Comment: @user535733 Thanks for the great hint. I updated the BIOS and the problem is solved! :)